# Why do I have to press buttons twice to play audio?

Tags: jquery, html5-audio

I made a simple program with some buttons. When a user clicks a button they should hear the corresponding sound.

The first time you press any given button. The button must be pressed twice to hear the sound. Every time thereafter pressing the button only once will work.

I am not experienced with jquery or javascript for that matter. For the most part, copied and pasted different examples I found online to get what I have now.

```
<style>
    p.hideme {display: none;}
</style>

<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="3" value="Sound 3" onclick=" play_sound3()">

<p class="hideme">
    <audio controls id="linkAudio3">
        <source src="sounds/sound3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
 </p>

<script>
    function play_sound3()
    {
        document.getElementById("3").addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.getElementById("linkAudio3").play();
  });
} 
</script>
```

The expected behaviour is that when a button is pressed a sound should play.

What actually happens is that on the first press of any button the button must be pressed twice for the sound to play

After that, the program works as expected.

Comment: You have an inline event handler on the button `onclick=" play_sound3()"` that calls a function that setups another event handler for a click event `.addEventListener("click",`. This is the problem, *and* you're adding new event handlers every time you click your button. You can get rid of the function's event handler, but the proper solution would be to scrap the inline one instead, and write code that sets up the event handler separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two event handlers; one on your button:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="3" value="Sound 3" onclick=" play_sound3()">
```

and one in your function which the button calls:

```
document.getElementById("3").addEventListener("click", function ()
```

Not only will this repeatedly add multiple event handlers every time you click your button, it's the reason you have the double click issue.

I'd recommend removing the inline event handler and just creating the single event handler placed at the end of your document like:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("3").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("linkAudio3").play();
} 
</script>
```

*Also, avoid using numeric IDs...

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is logical and resolved my issue.